# Showing Pi on button Text in design

Tags: android

Below is the code to show the x power y on button

```
btnXPowY = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnXPowY);
btnXPowY.setText(Html.fromHtml("x<sup>y</sup"));
```

Is there any way to do the same for Pi whose value is 22/7

Comment: 22/7 isn't pi. It's an approximation. Java has Math.PI constant defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Unicode value for the symbol, preceded by \u. For example, the pi character is `"\u03C0"`

refer this site for more characters http://inamidst.com/stuff/unidata/

Comment: I tried your code like this : `btnPi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPi); btnPi.setText(Html.fromHtml("\\u03C0"));` but it shows u03C0 on button

Comment: you have to use like this `btnPi.setText("\u03C0");`

Comment: Or you can just copy this character: π

Comment: While this may work (I never have done Android development), it is worth mentioning that `\unnnn` is *not* how you normally write Unicode characters *in HTML*. In HTML, it is `&#nnnnn;` (decimal) or `&#xnnnn;` (hexadecimal).